# Using a param as the argument to XSL select statement

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am using apache fop to produce a PDF, I have an XSL-FO template that produces a table and I would like to be able to call the template multiple times, with different select parameters.

here is my xsl stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template name="checklist">
        <xsl:param name="H1"/>
        <xsl:param name="H2"/>
        <xsl:param name="H3"/>
        <xsl:param name="src"/>
        <fo:block width="19cm" >
            <fo:table  font-size="8pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.2cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="16.5cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.2cm"/>
                <fo:table-header font-weight="bold" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$H1"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$H2"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$H3"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$src" />

                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <fo:table-row line-stacking-strategy="line-height" margin="0mm" space-before="1mm" background-color="white">
            <xsl:variable name="hdr" select="hdr"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$hdr = 'y'">
                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3" background-color="lightgrey" border="1px solid #b8b6b6">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:inline>
                                <xsl:value-of select="id"/>&#x00A0;
                                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1px solid #b8b6b6" vertical-align="middle" text-align="center">
                        
                        <fo:block line-height="4mm">
                            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1px solid #b8b6b6" padding-left="3pt">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1px solid #b8b6b6" text-align="center" padding-right="3pt">
                        <xsl:variable name="outcome" select="outcome"/>
                        <fo:block color="white">
                            <!--<fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/c1.svg" width="4.0mm" height="4.0mm" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>-->
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'ok'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/c1n.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="4.0mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'c1'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/ok.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.9mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'c2'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/c2.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.8mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'c3'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/c3.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.7mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'fi'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/fi.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.6mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'nv'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/nv.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.5mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'na'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/na.svg" vertical-align="middle"  height="3.4mm"  content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$outcome = 'lim'">
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="file:///F:/Projects/Active/eCert/src/resources/lim.svg" vertical-align="middle" height="3.3mm" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </fo:block>
                
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is one of the flows that calls the template

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block />
                    <xsl:call-template name="checklist">
                        <xsl:with-param name="H1" select="'Item No.'"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="H2" select="'Description'"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="H3" select="'Outcome'"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="src" select="'eicr/checklist/item'"/>
                        
                    </xsl:call-template>
                        
                </fo:flow>
```

When I execute FOP I get the following error ** Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!**
Parameters H1, H2 and H3 are used as the column headers and that part works fine
The src param is the one that should be used to select the items from from an xml list.

I am new xsl fo so any help or pointers to documentation that can help me achieve the desired result would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Your error is liekly here: <xsl:apply-templates select="$src" />

"src" represents a param passed into the XSLT externally. This is always a string. You would need to use an xslt extension to parse the string "src" into a node-set before

Comment: @KevinBrown In the code above, `$src` is a parameter passed to the called template internally - and it can be of any data type.

Comment: You are  correct. Need to read these things on computer and not phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single-quotes around `eicr/checklist/item`. `'eicr/checklist/item'` is a string literal; `eicr/checklist/item` is a location path that will select elements relative to the context node.

---

The alternative that I was trying to avoid (because it's more verbose) is to apply templates before or as part of calling the template and then just copying the result to the result tree:

```
<xsl:with-param name="src">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="eicr/checklist/item" />
</xsl:with-param>
```

```
<fo:table-body>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$src" />
</fo:table-body>
```

It's a technique that you see in the DocBook XSLT 1.0 stylesheets, e.g.:

https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets/blob/6ff683948c5a85949e4b7661f302e8b5f12f7bf2/xsl/fo/block.xsl#L181

Comment: I have tried without the single quotes <xsl:with-param name="src" select="eicr/checklist/item"/> and still get the same error SEVERE: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!

Comment: @JReynolds, it seems odd that you continue to get the same error. It is always hard to solve problems in comments, as the poster you can always edit your question and provide more information in a detailed and well-formatted way there. So perhaps add the new info to your question. Also, is the line number really 0? Is there no indication as to which line or statement causes the error?